# Unity Horizontal Input is Always -1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

Whenever I'm making a game (3D or 2D) and I use Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); Without pressing any buttons, my input is always -1. This problem only shows up with Unity.

[Inputs for Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDpuB.png)

To test, I played other video games (some made with Unity & some not made with Unity) and they work fine. Only one or two games made with Unity kept thinking I'm holding down either the left arrow key or the "A" key.

While in play mode, if I press the "D" key, I'll move to the right and when I take my finger off the key, it moves back to the left as if I'm pressing the "A" key.

Somethings when I enter play mode, the Vertical Input will also receive inputs that are not given.
Note: This happens at the very start (when I click the play button).
[Console & Game (no inputs by me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7UJS.png)

[Same Input in a UI Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8TqB.png)

My Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 moveDirection;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        ProcessInputs();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
    }

    void ProcessInputs()
    {
        float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        print("X: " + moveX + " | Y: " + moveY);

        moveDirection = new Vector2(moveX, moveY).normalized;
    }

    void Move()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x * moveSpeed, moveDirection.y * moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might rather want to use `GetAxisRaw` in your case .. `GetAxis` is interpolated smoothly.. but since you normalize the input it will just stay pressed longer even though you already let go

Comment: @derHugo I tried using GetAxisRaw, but, it still moved without inputs. However, if I freeze the rigidbody constraints at the start and then unfreeze them, the movement works fine for a couple of minutes, then goes back to moving without inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem comes from the "Project Settings". Search in "Input Manager" duplicate entries for "Horizontal". Remove second in the list by rightclick "delete array element".

After removing all duplicates in project settings the value of

```
 forwardInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
```

is "0" if no key is pressed.